# Got UnsupportedOperationException when expecting a SQL error

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I have a Spring boot application which we are deploying on Websphere Liberty packaged as a war. I have been getting a UnsupportedOperationException where I was expecting a SQL Error due to a mismatch in column name. Below is the stack trace:

```
SQL Error: -407, SQLState: 23502
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, SQLERRMC=TBSPACEID=2, TABLEID=4, COLNO=20, DRIVER=4.16.53
HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
HHH000337: Unable to mark for rollback on PersistenceException:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter.setRollbackOnly(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.markForRollbackOnly(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1509)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.handlePersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1585)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1693)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(EntityManagerImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2967)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter$TransactionAdapter$1.invoke(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:158)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy178.beforeCompletion(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.jtaextensions.SynchronizationCallbackWrapper.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackWrapper.java:71)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredSyncs.coreDistributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:291)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredSyncs.distributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:192)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.prePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:1663)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.stage1CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1057)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:975)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:237)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.uowCommit(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:873)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.uowEnd(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:851)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:793)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:368)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:290)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:299)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
```

While searching for a solution I had come across this question [Unexpected UnsupportedOperationException on Hibernate validation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388069/unexpected-unsupportedoperationexception-on-hibernate-validation-failure). However, it has been quite sometime this question has been asked and wanted to know if there is a easier way around which is not JPA implementation specific.Would greatly appreciate if someone explains why this is happening.

**EDIT**: while initially it looked like upgrading hibernate version as per Andy's answer below has solved the issue, it actually hasn't. I am still getting the error.

Liberty Version on which solution working - **8.5.5.7**

Liberty Version on which solution not working - **8.5.5.9 and above**

Below are snippets of my pom:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.13.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>             
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>                           
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>             
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance, feel free to ask for more details if required.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by Hibernate having outdated transaction integration code for WebSphere.

If you are able to upgrade to Hibernate 5.2.13 or newer, I recently delivered the proper WebSphere transaction integration in this Hibernate issue: 
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11571

Once you upgrade to the newer version of Hibernate, no other code/config changes should be needed on your end -- it should just work.

---

If for some reason it does not work out of the box, try explicitly setting this property in your persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
          value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereLibertyJtaPlatform" />
```

You will know if the new JTA integration was applied successfully if you no longer see the `WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform` class in the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks.Upgrading to hibernate 5.2.13 worked great. However, what can be done if upgrading is not an option?

Comment: If you are unable to upgrade to hibernate 5.2.13, you can write your own transaction integration code, which is provided in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41875770/3814029

Comment: @bidishamukherjee looks like accepted answer check got removed -- did you run into a problem with this approach?

Comment: Yes, I have upadated my question with the details..can you plz check?

Comment: Added another snippet which will allow you to explicitly state the new Liberty JTA platform (even though it should be getting picked up automatically).  Also, can you confirm you no longer see `WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform` in your stack trace?  That's the old JTA platform that was the default before 5.2.13.

Comment: I'll check with this